# How to fix all the flicker when rendering

Tags: rendering, objects, shaders, shadows, shadeless

I made something in Blender today. But when I rendered it has some black streaks flicker around the faces of object. I'm not sure how to fix the problem, I tried a few methods but it didn't work out for me.

This is the gif and images:
[image]

[image]

Here is my render setting and my geometric nodes:
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the denoise? If so, what does it give if you disable it, or change its settings, or increase the Sampling?

Comment: You might need to provide a lot more information about your rendering settings -- perhaps a screenshot of the render panel with several fields showing.  I agree with moonboots that "denoise" can be one source of this aberrant result.

Comment: Seems like it would be overlapping faces

Comment: @AllenSimpson I agree, looks like overlapping faces to me as well . But since I don't know how the object was created I cannot suggest a way to avoid them, only that they should be avoided.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not sure but the denoise that you're talking about is the viewport denoise, right? If so, I tried to untick the denoise and increase the sampling but it doesn't really change.

Comment: @james_t Thank you. I just added some screenshots of my rendering settings above, I did try to tick off the denoise but seems like it doesn't change.

Comment: @AllenSimpson Thanks for your comment. I made the objects with geometric nodes (I just added the screenshot of my geometric node above). I also think it overlapping too, but that is the main thing about the object. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for your info. I created the object with geometric nodes, the same way to create the city. I just added a screenshot of my node above. I also believe it overlaps faces as well but I can't really change it because it is the whole point of this object. Do you have any suggestions to remove the flicker things or reduce them?

Comment: the gif is too small to really see what's going on. The screenshots make me think about [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting#:~:text=Z%2Dfighting%2C%20also%20called%20stitching,which%20keeps%20track%20of%20depth.).